# Handling deps.json due to embedded assembly using Costura.Fody

Tags: c#, .net-core, fody, fody-costura

I have a .NET Core console application that references a .NET Standard assembly.
I've also added a NuGet package for Costura.Fody and a FodyWeavers.xml file (see below).

This builds fine and everything seems great, but when I try to run my app (`dotnet "MyApp.exe"`) it complains that it cannot find the file of the assembly that I've embedded mentioned in the MyApp.deps.json file.

The error message is:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
>   package: 'My.Assembly', version: '1.0.0.0'
>   path: 'My.Assembly.dll'

This makes sense and running the app works fine if I remove mentions from this file manually, but my question is: Is there a way to tell either Visual Studio or Costura to remove mentions of this assembly from my deps.json file so that I don't need to edit this after each build? Although I could whip up a tool to edit this during post-build, I would prefer a built-in way. I did not see anything documented on the Fody github page...

FodyWeavers.xml for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
  <Costura IncludeDebugSymbols="false">
    <IncludeAssemblies>
      My.Assembly
    </IncludeAssemblies>
  </Costura>
</Weavers>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution, perchance?

Comment: @aoven - Yes and no. I opened an issue on github around when I asked this, but no updates yet. What we are currently doing in manually removing references to embedded dependencies from the deps.json and this seems to work. It's just tedious because that file gets rebuilt each time (helps that git discards changes easily). There are future plans in place for a tool to automate this removal, but unfortunately it's extremely low priority, so for the meantime I'll be removing them manually...

Comment: Update for future readers: Looks like [the github issue was closed as stale](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/282) in Aug 2018. I suppose I could post my manual workaround (see prev comment) as an answer, but I'm not sure that's all that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Delete deps.json and run your app.

That file is really unnecesary.

Comment: I used to think this also but this GitHub issue response leads me to believe otherwise: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38275#issuecomment-966490986